# Best way to keep high available single instance with external static IP on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

once in a while we need a single server for a specific purpose that won't get high traffic.
For my scenario, this server requires a static external IP

I'm wondering what is the best way to have a high-available single server with static external IP on GCP?

Usually, we'd choose to create an instance-group with 1 minimal and 1 maximum instance, but that wouldn't keep the static IP for egress traffic after an instance crash/recreation.
So, I'd have to create an instance-group with no external IP and make the egress traffic going through a NAT Gateway + a Load Balancer for another static IP for the ingress traffic.

The problem is, that sounds too much for a single server.

On AWS it can be achieved in an easier way. It's just:

1. Launching one instance
2. Associate an external IP address to it
3. Create a Life cycle snapshot for backing up data
4. Create alarm to restart or restore the instance in case of system or instance failure

So, my question is: Is there some easier way to achieve this on Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to do in GCP what you're asking but it not easier. At least from the list of steps perspective.

Here's how you can do it:

1. [Reserve static public IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)
2. Create a VM [with external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance) from #1
3. [Create a Snapshot Schedule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots#create_snapshot_schedule) and attach it to a VM's persistent disk
4. [Create an uptime check](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#create) and an [alert](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp) that will publish it via [pub/sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview)
5. Create a [GCP Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/save-money-by-stopping-and-starting-compute-engine-instances-on-schedule) job to restart desired VM based on pub/sub events.